How to install rabbitmq server on a mapped network drive
I am trying to install the latest versions of rabbitmq server and erlang on a mapped network drive using Windows (10 specifically). The Folder referenced is from a different machine
In order to do this I've tried setting HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH variables to the select drive.
After installing ERLANG and RabbitMQ when I try to start the service (last step of the installation) I got this error:
The RabbitMQ service failed to start due to the following error: 
Access is denied.

I've tried running as an Admin but the result is the same. I've tried also the following:
> rabbitmq-service.bat remove
> set HOMEDRIVE=Z:
> rabbitmq-service.bat install
> rabbitmq-service.bat start
The RabbitMQ service is starting.
The RabbitMQ service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.

Is there a missing setting or what should be the right procedure to install these programs in a mapped netword drive?
NOTE: I've tried using the volume letter and UNC paths

Hmm, why would you do that? A network drive might easily fail or go offline, making such a flow very fragile. I wouldn't be surprised that it doesn't start because it is intentionally filtering out network/unreliable drives.
You can easily verify this though, just try on a regular drive and see if that works.

Thanks for answering. On a regular drive works as expected however I am trying to use the mapped networks

In that case I would ask through their support channels... Stackoverflow isn't the right place for this, for one thing it mostly concerns code.
